# How does this use of WallpaperManager work?

Tags: android

To set background without having errors I had to use someone elses code, and I don't know what it does. Can someone please explain it?

```
WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = 
                 WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
```

Answer (score 0):

It will give you the instance of `WallpaperManager`.

For information on `WallpaperManager`, refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

Read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#getInstance%28android.content.Context%29):

> > Retrieve a WallpaperManager associated with the given Context.